# ¿Es legal leer imágenes y descripciones de otro sitio web y ponerlas en mi app?

Tags: java, woocommerce

¿Es legal leer imágenes y descripciones de otro sitio web y ponerlas en mi programa?

Supongamos que quiero hacer una aplicación como la de *ebay*, y al empezar no tiene personas que pongan productos, ya que es nueva.

Y en mi programa escribo un código que lea los productos de ebay y su descripción, y los muestro en mi aplicación ¿Es legal esto?

Comment: Te recomiendo la api de flickr o la de google imágenes. :) Ah también esta la api de thumblr y de instagram

Answer (score 3):

Fijate los términos y condiciones de cada sitio. La mayoría no permite hacer uso de su contenido, mucho menos si es con fines lucrativos como parece ser tu proyecto.

Algo que te puede resultar útil es ver si tiene algún enlace o API para incorporar a tu pagina web como es el caso de [Google Maps](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/144361?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=es-419) o el [Boton de suscripcion de Youtube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_subscribe_button?hl=es), ya que de esa forma te aseguras que te den el permiso para enlazar contenido de ellos en tu página.